# How to call another function on clicking of Modal button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I want to use bootstrap modal in my page. At the same time, when modal trigger button is clicked, I want to do something in javascript also. It's not working.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary center-block" id="start_quiz" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
    Start Quiz
</button>
```

The button on clicking lauches modal but unable to call:

```
$('#start_quiz').click(function(){
            alert("hello from javascript");  
        });
```

How can I achieve both results at the same time? Please help me.

Comment: do you want some action on when modal open?

Comment: Your example appears to be working as far as I can tell, here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4rsk5vor/) of it working.

Comment: @chirag Yes, I want to achieve an ajax call

Comment: @AnishPatel I don't think it is working..Let me check

Comment: Do you only want the modal to open if some condition is met in your function?

Comment: Yes, I want to do two tasks, one to open modal and simultaneously fetch data from backend.

Comment: refer answer by @bgs264

Comment: Then your example is working, refer to the fiddle I set up. The modal only shows up after you acknowledge the alert because its an alert which will block until its acknowledged. Swap it out for a console.log if you want.

Comment: @AnishPatel You are right. It was working earlier. I was not loading jquer.js properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"` attributes from the button, so that it doesn't open the modal.

Then check that the "hello from javascript" displays - it should do.

Then open the modal from javascript code instead, add this line below your alert:

`$('#myModal').modal('show')`

This should now make the alert, then show the modal. You can always reverse the two if you want the modal shown first.

**Second option**, hook into the shown method and write your javascript there:

```
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
  // alert here
})
```